# Unable to link pages from JSP Page

Tags: html, jsp

```
<div class="navbar-collapse  collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" >
          <li class="active"><a href="Sponsors.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="Sponsors.html">Sponsors</a></li>
          <li><a href="Accomodation">Accomodation</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Our Team</a></li>

         <li><a>Social Cause</a></li>
         <li><a href="Mard.html">Events</a></li>
         <li><a href="signup"> Registration</a></li>
         <li><a href="">Admin Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

This is the above code that I using to create navigation menu in JSP page. I have some HTML pages in my project too. Its not working.

Comment: Could you please share complete code or make fiddle ?

Comment: Sorry... I am unable to understand what you are exactly asking for. I have posted the actual code using to create navigation.

Comment: I mean any working link where I can see the actual problem.

Comment: I am creating it on NETBEANS... I am not using word press... How i would able to provide you the working link... I am extremely sorry for asking silly questions but i am new to this website..

Comment: can you show project directory structure ?

Comment: C:\Users\Acer\Documents\NetBeansProjects\TECHSCRIPT\build\web

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your html files locates under Web-Inf folder.

Comment: My files are located under this link :-  C:\Users\Acer\Documents\NetBeansProjects\TECHSCRIPT\build\web

Comment: I have tried almost everthing . Intially it worked for just one time and after that its not working

Comment: use   <li><a href="../Mard.html">Events</a></li> instead